# J meter with selenium Scripts

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to run the J meter with Selenium scripts while blow errors is displaying.

```
Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2022-03-07 15:48:33 IST
Load time:5007
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:1005
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:1005
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:500
Response message:In file: inline evaluation of: ``WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();      WDS.browser.get("http://google.com . . . '' Encountered "." at line 5, column 13.
 in inline evaluation of: ``WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();      WDS.browser.get("http://google.com . . . '' at line number 5


SampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/plain
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

The `error` you are getting.

> Response message:In file: inline evaluation of:
> ``WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
> WDS.browser.get("http://google.com . . . '' Encountered "." at line 5,
> column 13.

Saying you have an `.` at line 5, column 13. This means that there is some sort of syntax error in the script. It's self explanatory.